# Return odd indexed values from tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
def oddTuples(aTup):

    # Your Code Here
    tup = ();
    for t in aTup:
        if t%2 != 0:
            tup = tup + (t,);
    return tup;

print(oddTuples(((1), (2), (2), (23), (3), (4))))
```

I got output (1, 23, 3) but I don't want this output I tried to so many times but I don't get

I want to print odd index just like output (1, 2, 3)

Comment: It doesn't like like you're clear on what you want. 1, 2, and 3 are located at even indices (because python is 0-index based).

Comment: Ok forget that output what I mention. 0 index based fine so I want to print out odd index value.  How can I?

Comment: i think you want the odd indexed (1-indexed) tuples but you are using `t in aTup`  it traverses the array and so you can't really divide it by 2 and check. use `for t in range(len(aTup)):` alternative is python slice notation `aTup[0::2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
def oddTuples(aTup):
    return aTup[::2]

print(oddTuples(((1), (2), (2), (23), (3), (4))))
# (1, 2, 3)
```

**Explanation**

- Tuples, like lists, accept slicing syntax, the final part of the slicing syntax indicates every 2nd element is chosen.
- Since no start parameter is specified, the first element is included.

Comment: Awesome bro it's working thanks for clearing this enigma!

Answer (score 1):

```
def oddTuples(aTup):
    return aTup[0::2]

print(oddTuples(((1), (2), (2), (23), (3), (4))))
```

It will print what you want:
`(1, 2, 3)`

Answer (score 0):

This will work!

```
def oddTuples(aTup):

    # Your Code Here
    tup = ();
    for i in range(0,len(aTup)):
        if i%2 == 0:
            tup = tup + (aTup[i],);
    return tup;

print(oddTuples(((1), (2), (2), (23), (3), (4))))
```